# Python Data Scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wrote the following line of code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#weather.scraper

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

def main():
    """weather scraper"""
    r = urllib.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KPHL/2016/1/1/MonthlyHistory.html?&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=&MR=1").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find_all("table", class_="responsive airport-history-summary-table")
    tr = soup.find_all("tr")
    td = soup.find_all("td")
    print table
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I print the table i get all the html (td, tr, span, etc.) as well. How can I print the content of the table (tr, td) without the html?
THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `.getText()` method when you want to get a content. Since `find_all` returns a list of elements, you have to choose one of them (`td[0]`).

Or you can do for example:

```
for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    print '>>>> NEW row <<<<'
    print '|'.join([x.getText() for x in tr.find_all('td')])
```

The loop above prints for each row cell next to cell.

Note that you do find all `td`'s and all `tr`'s your way but you probably want to get just those in `table`.

If you want to look for elements inside the `table`, you have to do this:

`table.find('tr')` instead of `soup.find('tr)` so the `BeautifulSoup` will be looking for `tr`s in the `table` instead of whole `html`.

YOUR CODE MODIFIED (according to your comment that there are more tables):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#weather.scraper

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

def main():
    """weather scraper"""
    r = urllib.urlopen("https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KPHL/2016/1/1/MonthlyHistory.html?&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=&MR=1").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    tables = soup.find_all("table")

    for table in tables:
        print '>>>>>>> NEW TABLE <<<<<<<<<'

        trs = table.find_all("tr")

        for tr in trs:
            # for each row of current table, write it using | between cells
            print '|'.join([x.get_text().replace('\n','') for x in tr.find_all('td')])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Indeed you are write about td`s in the table. but if I try `tr = table.find('tr')` I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: Because it's a list. If you have just one table in html, you have to do soup.find('table'....  instead of soup.find_all('table....

Comment: But in the complete html there are more tables, I am specifying my search by stating a class. I am not quite sure what you mean...

Comment: @malina Check my answer, I've edited there your code.

Comment: Now it's for all tables in the web page.